# TypeError: removeAttr is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть обработчик события вставки:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#edit-input-wrap').on("paste",function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var clipboarddata =  window.event.clipboardData.getData('text/html');
        if(clipboarddata != null){
            var div_array = Array.prototype.slice.call($(clipboarddata));
            var i = 0;
            while (i < div_array.length){
                if(div_array[i].nodeName === 'SPAN'){
                    var objClipboardData = $(clipboarddata)[i].innerHTML.replace(/&nbsp;/g, ' ');
                    i = div_array.length;
                }
                else if(div_array[i].nodeName === 'IMG'){
                    var objClipboardData = $(clipboarddata)[i].outerHTML.removeAttr('style');
                    i = div_array.length;
                }
                i++;
            }
        }
        txt_paste = document.getElementById('edit-input-wrap').innerHTML.replace(/&nbsp;/g, ' ');
        txt_paste = txt_paste.substring(0, window.getSelection().anchorOffset).replace(/&nbsp;/g, ' ') + objClipboardData + txt_paste.substring(window.getSelection().anchorOffset);
        document.getElementById('edit-input-wrap').innerHTML = txt_paste;
    });
});
```

Я хочу удалить стили из объекта `$(clipboarddata)[i]` и вечно ошибка `removeAttr is not a function`. Помогите решить проблему.

Comment: ...outerHTML.prop('style', '');

Comment: @Konst , тоже ошибка, `Uncaught TypeError: $(...)[i].outerHTML.prop is not a function`.
@РустамГимранов , у меня `<div id='edit-input-wrap' contenteditable='true' >Текст...</div>`

Comment: Не получается воспроизвести.В-общем вам надо сначала атрибут удалить,  а уже потом брать разметку: `$($(clipboarddata)[i]).removeAttr('style').get(0).outerHTML`

Comment: @РустамГимранов , спасибо огромное! Добавьте это в виде ответа, отмечу.